# Store data persistently in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8

I have a rather general question. I have made an app that uses a large word list. These words are stored in a text file along with the source code. On the initial launch of the app I populate a data object with words from the text file. This data object is then used for each new startup as it is persistent and the text file is never used again.

I find this solution to be a bit weird to be honest. Is it possible to rather pre-populate/pre-compile such a data object using built-in iOS functionality? I'm thinking along the lines of having a .sqlite file that already has all the data stored in it on the first launch, as one would do in any other language I've worked with.

All answers are welcome!

Comment: There are a dozen ways to handle this, but all will require storing the data *somewhere* between app executions.  Having a SQLite file in your bundle is a perfectly valid approach, eg, and there are dozens of examples of how to do this (though perhaps not in Swift) here on SO, if you look.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, there are lots of different ways to handle this.

What I haven done is to create a Mac program that opens the text file, converts it to an array, and then saves the array as a **binary** plist. Binary plists are faster and more storage-efficient than text-based plists. I then add the plist to my iOS project and that's what I read at startup.

You could just as easily do the conversion from an iOS project.

Take a look at the **`NSPropertyListSerialization`** class for info on creating a binary plist, and specifically the `kCFPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0` value for the `format` parameter of the 
`-dataWithPropertyList:format:options:error:` method.

If you need fast indexed searching of your word list then another storage format like SQL might be a better choice, but you can do the conversion from text to whatever target format you want as part of the development process and include the converted file in your project.

Comment: I second the binary plist suggestion. PLists are a good way to go for what you're looking to do, because they're editable using a text-editor, and when you convert them to binary, your operation is sped up even further.

Comment: Text-based plists are not super fast, but binary plists are both fast and memory efficient. It's pretty easy to use the `NSPropertyListSerialization` object as suggested, and specify a format of `NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0` while testing, then switch to the binary `NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0` format once you're satisfied that everything is working, for a savings in both disk space (large) and performance.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use `NSUserDefaults`. You should store an NSArray or NSDictionary with the values you need there. On your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`, you could add:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if([userDefaults objectForKey:@"wordsData"] == nil){
    //This means this is the first time the user opens the app. Create defaults.
    //Create a dictionary or an array with the words.
    NSDictionary *wordsDictionary = <my dictionary>; 
    [userDefaults setObject:wordsDictionary forKey:@"wordsData"];
    [userDefaults synchronise];
}
```

Then, when you need to retrieve them, use:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *wordsDictionary = [defaults objectForKey:@"wordsData"];
```

If you need more on NSUserDefaults, read [the Apple docs regarding NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html).
Note: `NSUserDefaults` doesn't have a limit, but you shouldn't save more than 512KB data there. If you need much more than this, you should look forward to `NSBundle` or other storage types. The data stored on the `NSUserDefaults` goes to a .plist file, so it shouldn't be too large.

Best regards,

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer but I think having this kind of data in `NSUserDefaults`' is **not** ideal because having them in as an array or dictionary will require you to read the entire list at load time. This will increase the load time of your application sooner than you think. NSUserDefaults should be used, as its name suggests, for settings, preferences, flags, usually cheap/small things.

Comment: I agree with Nacho. It's best to avoid storing large data sets in user defaults. Another option like a plist, file created using NSCoding, or an SQL database would be a better choice.